# ProgressDialog wheel not spinning

Tags: android, button, android-activity, progressdialog

Here  is the code of my button activity, i managed to add a progressdialog so when the actvity sciencetechnology is loading its shows loading..only it isn't spinning so i'm wondering what im doing wrong, maby someone can look for my mistake here is the code:

```
package net.thinkbin;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;

public class tutorial1 extends Activity{

private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tutorial1);

    Button share = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startActivity(new Intent("net.thinkbin.SHARE"));
            overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
            finish();
        }
    });

    Button menu = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonhome);
    menu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(tutorial1.this, "",   "Loading...");  
            Thread th = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run(){
                    startActivity(new  Intent("net.thinkbin.MENU"));
                    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    finish();
                }

            });
            th.start();

        }
    });

    Button culture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    culture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(tutorial1.this, "", "Loading...");  
            Thread th = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run(){
                    startActivity(new   Intent("net.thinkbin.CULTURE"));
                    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    finish();
                }

            });
            th.start();

        }
    });

    Button entertainment = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    entertainment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(tutorial1.this, "", "Loading...");  
            Thread th = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run(){
                    startActivity(new Intent("net.thinkbin.ENTERTAINMENT"));
                    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    finish();
                }

            });
            th.start();

        }
    });

    Button philosophy = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
    philosophy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(tutorial1.this, "", "Loading...");  
            Thread th = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run(){
                    startActivity(new Intent("net.thinkbin.PHILOSOPHY"));
                    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    finish();
                }

            });
            th.start();

        }
    });

    Button sciencetechnology = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
    sciencetechnology.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(tutorial1.this, "", "Loading...");  
            Thread th = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run(){
                    startActivity(new Intent("net.thinkbin.SCIENCETECHNOLOGY"));
                    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    finish();

                }

            });

            th.start();


        }
    });


}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't be sure, but I've only ever seen `Handler` or `AsyncTask` used to run a separate thread. Either way, here is an [example of using progressbar in android that works](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-progress-bar-example/).

Answer (score 0):

The way you are doing it currently is unconventional.

To get the spinning style action pre ICS you should call

```
showDialog(int);
```

and override

```
onCreateDialog(int);
```

to set the spinner style.

post ICS they have replaced all of this with the FragmentManager So you should use that to create the spinning style actions.

Answer (score 0):

You have better to use AsynTask in Android rather than Thread.

```
Button sciencetechnology = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
sciencetechnology.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       UrTask u=new UrTask ();
       u..execute();


    }
});
```

**AsynTask**

```
public class UrTask extends
        AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    ProgressDialog pDialog;

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ActivityName.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Downloading Data...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {

        // Do ur work

        return (null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }

}
```